# How to reproduce Hazelcast OperationTimeoutException: [CONCURRENT_MAP_CONTAINS_KEY]

Tags: caching, concurrency, timeout, cluster-computing, hazelcast

Under load, using Hazlecast 2.4, we encountered the following Hazlecast exception in a cluster. As it seems the underlying issue has been addressed in Hazlecast 2.5. In order to validate that the upgrade indeed addresses the same issue we encountered we would like to reproduce it. In our current setup it only occurs rarely. How can we reproduce it under lab conditions?

I noticed
[Hazelcast - OperationTimeoutException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28570609/hazelcast-operationtimeoutexception)
which may be related.

```
com.hazelcast.core.OperationTimeoutException: [CONCURRENT_MAP_CONTAINS_KEY] Operation Timeout (with no response!): 0
               at com.hazelcast.impl.BaseManager$ResponseQueueCall.waitAndGetResult(BaseManager.java:619)
               at com.hazelcast.impl.BaseManager$ResponseQueueCall.getRedoAwareResult(BaseManager.java:641)
               at com.hazelcast.impl.BaseManager$ResponseQueueCall.getResult(BaseManager.java:636)
               at com.hazelcast.impl.BaseManager$RequestBasedCall.getResultAsBoolean(BaseManager.java:447)
               at com.hazelcast.impl.BaseManager$ResponseQueueCall.getResultAsBoolean(BaseManager.java:555)
               at com.hazelcast.impl.BaseManager$RequestBasedCall.booleanCall(BaseManager.java:432)
               at com.hazelcast.impl.BaseManager$ResponseQueueCall.booleanCall(BaseManager.java:555)
               at com.hazelcast.impl.ConcurrentMapManager$MContainsKey.containsKey(ConcurrentMapManager.java:622)
               at com.hazelcast.impl.MProxyImpl$MProxyReal.containsKey(MProxyImpl.java:937)
               at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor322.invoke(Unknown Source)
               at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
               at com.hazelcast.impl.MProxyImpl$DynamicInvoker.invoke(MProxyImpl.java:66)
               at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy180.containsKey(Unknown Source)
               at com.hazelcast.impl.MProxyImpl.containsKey(MProxyImpl.java:312)
```

Comment: Probably time to move to Hazelcast 3.x. The 2.x branch afaik isn't supported anymore.

Comment: Thanks, it does not matter to which version we upgrade. In order to validate a fix we need to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Reproducing the infamous OperationTimeoutException is very time consuming; trust me.. I spend a ton of time on it. For 3.x we have created a stress testing environment that allows us the test the whole HZ system, but also lower level components like IO without the stuff on top. This gives us some insight in the stability. The problem with the OperationTimeoutException is that all components need to work in perfect harmony; if one component fails..e.g. io.. or same data race while processing, there won't be a response for the operation and you get this failure.

Comment: Hazelcast 3.x is a total rewrite from Hazelcast 2.x btw.